# What are the options for named locks in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have the following code:

```
private static readonly object cacheLock = new object();
void foo(string key) {
  lock(cacheLock) {
    // perform calcs on a key
  }
}
```

This works but blocks too much since there is only a single lock object - therefore I am looking for an approach where the lock object is named - to reduce contention.

I've tried the ConcurrentDictionary approach:

```
class NamedMonitor {
  readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> _dictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>();
  public object this[string name] => _dictionary.GetOrAdd(name, _ => new object());
}
```

And then:

```
private static NamedMonitor locker = new NamedMonitor();
lock (locker[name]) {
  // ...
}
```

I am not a fan of that because the _dictionary inside the NamedMonitor class just grows unchecked.

I've also tried the Mutex object, which does allow named entries, but it's OS wide and therefore slower than other approaches.

What other approaches are there for named locks?  Ideally I'd like to have code like this:

```
void foo(string key) {
  lock(String.Intern(key)) {
    // perform calcs on a key
  }
}
```

but I am not sure that this is safe enough.

Comment: `String.Intern(key)` - strings are never un-interned, so this has the same unchecked growth problem as your `NamedMonitor`, although it's more hidden.

Comment: If there's too much lock contention, I'd first try and reduce the scope of the lock. You haven't said what "calcs" you're doing, but is there any way you can hold the lock for a shorter time?

Comment: Why do you think your dictionary of locks would grow unbounded? If your application needs _N_ locks, why would it start using _N+1_ of them? And if you need an unbounded number of locks, you need to revise your application design.

Comment: Another common way to reduce contention is to have a fixed size array of lock objects and hash the key to pick a lock out of the array. That way your contention is divided by whatever the size of your array is and you don't have to worry about the "unchecked growth" of your proposals. This is assuming you have a good hash function and use of the keys is evenly distributed.

Comment: @xxbbcc The locks would be based on the passed in key.  Which in itself is built from a physical address.  So there is a potential limitless amount of locks.

Comment: @AngryHacker In that case I'd suggest you reconsider this implementation. A limitless number of locks won't scale well - locks are local to the computer to begin with. If you truly have a need for a limitless number of locks, why would you be worried about unbounded growth? In that case, you need many computers anyway and using locks is not the right tool. Maybe database-based locking would work better but that's hard to say because your question doesn't have enough details for that.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to introduce tricky approaches to implement a per-key level state protection inside the collection level functionality I'd suggest to make some separation of concerns. As per what can be deduced from your code snippets you have some functionality which operates on the per-key level and which has concurrent nature. This in turn implies that a per-key state you're trying to protect should be existing (already constructed at some point). Then why not to wrap this state and corresponding functionality into separate class which in addition would be responsible for the state protection from the race conditions instead of mixing the higher level protection of entire collection state with element level protection in the same unit and which may look like as follows:

```
public class Item
{
    private readonly object _locker = new object();

    public void Foo()
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            // perform calcs
        }
    }
}

void foo(string key)
{
    // the getItem may also require protection but on the collection level
    Item item = getItem(key);
    item?.Foo();
}
```

As a per-key state is already there you're just wrapping it into the class which in that case is responsible of per-key state protection and implicitly controls the lock object lifecycle.